# Select User who don't own a specific item

Tags: mysql

```
                          Tables
 __________                     
|__users__|                     
|_id_|    |                     
| A  |    |                     
| B  |    |     
| C  |    |     
 ---------     


___________________________
|___________owns__________|
|___userId___|___itemId___|
| A          | 1          |
| A          | 2          |
| B          | 1          |
| C          | 2          |
| C          | 3          |
 -------------------------
```

How do I select the users who don't own item 1.  In this case, it should be user C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use `LEFT JOIN` as follows:

```
SELECT id 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT userId from owns WHERE itemId=1)x ON id=userId 
WHERE userId IS NULL;
```

Example:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM users;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
| A    |
| B    |
| C    |
+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM owns;
+--------+--------+
| userId | itemId |
+--------+--------+
| A      |      1 |
| A      |      2 |
| B      |      1 |
| C      |      2 |
| C      |      3 |
+--------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

# Result of the subquery
mysql> SELECT userId from owns WHERE itemId=1;
+--------+
| userId |
+--------+
| A      |
| B      |
+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT id FROM users LEFT JOIN (SELECT userId from owns WHERE itemId=1)x ON id=userId WHERE userId IS NULL;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
| C    |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's typical query, that can be implemented with [`EXISTS()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) function:

```
SELECT
    *                           -- get fields
FROM
    users as u                  -- from users
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS(                 -- where there is no
        SELECT
            TRUE
        FROM
            owns as o           -- owns
        WHERE
            (o.userId = u.id)   -- with this user
            AND
            (o.itemId <> 1)     -- and such item
    );
```

For multiple items check you can use `IN()` in condition check of correlated subquery:

```
SELECT
    *                             -- get fields
FROM
    users as u                    -- from users
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS(                   -- where there is no
        SELECT
            TRUE
        FROM
            owns as o             -- owns
        WHERE
            (o.userId = u.id)     -- with this user
            AND
            (o.itemId IN (1, 3))  -- and items from subset
    );
```

Comment: Would the subquery work?  I see that there's no join between the users table and owns table.

Comment: Yes, it would work, because there is correlated condition, that acts like a `JOIN` you mentioned: `(o.userId = u.id)`. I mean, `owns.userId = users.id`.